# How can I build two Kivy apps in the same directory / environment / venv?

Tags: python, android, makefile, kivy

I'm playing with Kivy, and it's set up so that `make` will run the program on my linux box, and `make app` will build the android version and put it on my phone.

I'd like to have a 'test' version and a 'stable' version side by side in the same venv, which I could run with e.g. `make stable` and `make stableapp`.

But it seems that the main file must be called `main.py` for buildozer to create an android app.

It seems in some way evil to have stable.py and test.py, and get the makefile to rename/copy/soft link main.py just before doing the build, but that's the best idea I can come up with.

Anyone got any better ideas?

Comment: Using a conditional switch in main.py depending on $0 doesn't work?